# Share file between Mac with password?

Tags: sharing, password

Like the title says, I want to share files between two Macs with password enabled. I've tried to disable the access of guest account and using the account with password. But it doesn't work, the username and password from other mac doesn't match.

Information about my macs:

1. Mac Pro - Moutain Lion
2. Macbook pro - Lion

What I've tried:

1. Enable sharing folder and remove everyone's right to access the shared folder on Macbook.
2. Using Mac Pro to get the shared files.
3. If I don't remove the everyone's access right, I can use the shared files / folders normally

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you've done so far? What OS version are you using? What are you trying to achieve? Are the Macs in the same LAN? Near to each other?

Comment: @Thecafremo fyi

Comment: Besides the fact this question is illegal (we are not allowed to discuss Hackintosh software), have you tried AirDrop?

Comment: Thanks @Michiel for the suggestion, actually at first I thought it's just a beautiful interface to see who around.
I'm gonna try later when I back home and post the result here :)

Comment: @Michiel it works like champ. But it's gonna be nice if someone can answer this question :)

Comment: Tadaa :) Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for AirDrop!

[image]

You should be able to discover the Macs in your surroundings and then you can simply drag and drop the files.